# Как организовать ассоциации?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть две модели, Airport и Flight

У Flight может быть аэропорт вылета и аэропорт прилета

```
belongs_to :origin, class_name: 'Airport', foreign_key: :origin_id
belongs_to :destination, class_name: 'Airport', foreign_key: :destination_id
```

Airport может быть у многих рейсов как аэропортом вылета, так и аэропортом прилета

```
has_many :flights, foreign_key: :destination_id
has_many :flights, foreign_key: :origin_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ассоциация в Airport должна быть такой:

```
has_many :destination_flights, foreign_key: :destination_id, class_name: 'Flight'
has_many :origin_flights, foreign_key: :origin_id, class_name: 'Flight'
```